# Firebase user object is not fire new changes, upon user updated at child custom element

Tags: firebase, polymer, web-component

My code is : in `jj-login.html`

```
<paper-icon-item>
 <paper-avatar label="{{user.displayName}}" src="{{user.photoURL}}"></paper-avatar>
......
    <jj-social-icons user={{user}}></jj-social-icons>
```

At below `jj-social-icons.html` user object defined and notify true.

```
user:{type: Object,
       notify:true},
```

Upon linked social providers (like facebook twetter) I update user.displayName and user.photoURL with new credential's data. with:

```
user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
   if (profile.providerId==authId) {
      user.updateProfile({
           displayName: profile.displayName,
           photoURL: profile.photoURL
      }).then(function() {
        console.log("update succesfull"); // Update successful.
       }, function(error) {
          // An error happened.
      });  
    }

});
```

Update is successful. But at parent element (jj-login.html, above) user name and photo is not updated automatically. (changes is not effected) 
How to solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To notify the data system of a subproperty change, use [`this.notifyPath()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notify-path):

```
user.updateProfile(...).then(() => {
  this.notifyPath('user.displayName');
  this.notifyPath('user.photoURL');
});
```

Comment: Try `this.notifyPath('user.displayName')` and `this.notifyPath('user.photoURL')` instead.

Comment: That's great help Tony. Thank you very much really :)) Its now working :))

Comment: @Hakan No problem :)